# Visual Studio 2013 extensions and roaming profiles

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

Visual Studio 2013 ships with a couple of extensions that don't work properly if you have a roaming profile.  The symptoms are error messages when opening a C# project and (in some cases) when creating a new C# project.  (Other languages may also be affected.)

These errors occur on any machine other than the one on which you first ran Visual Studio, and seem to be related to the fact that extensions are stored in a path with a random component.

The problematic extensions are:

- Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
- NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2013

I believe that uninstalling these two extensions on all the machines will resolve the problem, but is there any other way?

The error messages in the activity log look like this:

```
  <entry>
    <record>311</record>
    <time>2015/05/08 02:41:35.021</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CreateInstance failed for package [NuGetVSEventsPackage]</description>
    <guid>{98BF0691-D23C-4897-A241-9CF5BEFDCC4A}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Tools, Version=2.8.50926.663, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>

  <entry>
    <record>312</record>
    <time>2015/05/08 02:41:35.021</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [NuGetVSEventsPackage]</description>
    <guid>{98BF0691-D23C-4897-A241-9CF5BEFDCC4A}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.Tools, Version=2.8.50926.663, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>

  <entry>
    <record>321</record>
    <time>2015/05/08 02:41:36.967</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CreateInstance failed for package [VSPackage]</description>
    <guid>{1A4EFADE-F6B2-4490-A2EF-21D5F3D1C8E0}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\v03a4uqf.jhe\Microsoft.AppInsights.GettingStarted.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>

  <entry>
    <record>322</record>
    <time>2015/05/08 02:41:36.967</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [VSPackage]</description>
    <guid>{1A4EFADE-F6B2-4490-A2EF-21D5F3D1C8E0}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\v03a4uqf.jhe\Microsoft.AppInsights.GettingStarted.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

There is one registry entry in HKCU that references the missing path:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\Packages\{1a4efade-f6b2-4490-a2ef-21d5f3d1c8e0}
    VsWinExpressId    REG_DWORD    0x4
    VWDExpressId    REG_DWORD    0x3
    MinEdition    REG_SZ    Standard
    ProductVersion    REG_SZ    1.0
    ProductName    REG_SZ    Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
    CompanyName    REG_SZ    Microsoft Corporation
    (Default)    REG_SZ    VSPackage
    InprocServer32    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\system32\MSCOREE.DLL
    Class    REG_SZ    Microsoft.AppInsights.GettingStarted.VSPackage
    CodeBase    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\tr5jvnqs.3lf\Microsoft.AppInsights.GettingStarted.dll
```

(NB: the registry entry posted was obtained from a different test run than the activity log was, which is why the random part of the paths don't match.)

Comment: have you tried doing devenv /setup or anything to see if your MEF cache is somehow messed up?

Comment: @JohnGardner: the problem occurs even on freshly reinstalled machines, clean test accounts, and is fully reproducible, so that seems unlikely.  However, I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: @JohnGardner: when devenv /setup is run as the administrator, does not affect this problem.  When it is run as the user, it just says "The operation could not be completed", presumably because it is failing to elevate.

Comment: bummer.  my team owns one of those extensions, so we're looking into it for ours (appinsights.gettingstarted), may or may not be the same problem for nuget (since I think we depend on them, we might be failing for the same reason they are? (or because they are?))

Comment: if you haven't already, can you use the send a smile/frown thing to report this as a bug?

Comment: @JohnGardner: done (under my email address, which is also shown in my SO profile, if you want to search for it) but I'm not sure whether it worked - it appears to be trying to connect directly to a web site rather than going through the proxy server.  I'll try again next week when I'm back at work, I can move one of the machines onto a network that has a direct internet connection.

Comment: for most of us, the feedback is anonymized, so I can't look it up that way, but i'm pretty sure I found it given other things that were above.  the more I've looked into it though, I don't think that as extension authors, we can fix this, as it is the VS VSIX machinery that installs us into that random location.  What's odd, though, is that something in your roaming profile knows about one location, when it shouldn't know about any of them... thanks for reporting though, if I find anything out, i'll let you know.

Comment: The only workaround I can think of to fix this would be to ensure you install VS to the machine using an admin account that does **not** have a roaming profile?

Comment: @JohnGardner: as it happens, we *do* install VS using the local Administrator account, which of course does not have a roaming profile or redirected application data folder. :-)  What puzzles me slightly is why I only get those two errors, I don't think those are the only extensions installed.

Comment: @JohnGardner: the random part of the path appears in exactly one place in the user's registry hive (in a value named "CodeBase").  I've added it to the question.  I'm not sure whether the NuGet issue is the same or not, it doesn't seem to have a similar entry.  Looking through that part of the registry, most of the other packages seem to have constant paths, e.g., `Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\foo.dll`.